# Calendar sync with iCal format

Tags: php, icalendar

I've got a PHP (on Apache2) multi-users web application. This application stores in a database "calendar events" for each user.

Now I would like to give a (secured) READ-ONLY subscription to their events through their favourite calendar software, ie. Apple iCal. And I would like authentication to be done with existing username/password credentials stored in Web server database.

I plan to use PHP iCalcreator class to transform on-the-fly the events to iCal format.

Each user will have their private iCal URL eg. https://mydomain.net/{user-ID}/ical.ics

Do I get a chance to make it work this way ? If so how to retrieve the username/password set in (Apple) iCal in order to do authentication on my Web server ?

In case this cannot work this way, could you advise me the easier solution ?

Also I wonder if (Apple) iCal transmit start_date and end_date parameters in order to limite the sync period ?

Thanks a lot.

Gregory

Answer (score 0):

Good questions. I'm also working on the same kind of project.

I don't have answers to all of your questions.

I think iCal and iCalCreator are good choices. I'm using iCalCreator and it's soo simple !

For the security issue I would say that you could give a token (in the URL) to each user from your php application, telling them not to communicate it. That's how google calendar does it I think. Your "web service" should maybe also be accessible with HTTPs to prevent eyedropping kind of hack.

For the dates range filtering from Apple iCal client, I'm also [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846873/ical-remote-query-filter) for some documentation on it.

Comment: Hi, good to know you are also trying to figure out a solution for this need. I've seen your [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846873/ical-remote-query-filter) and the answer. It is clear that for performance it is not acceptable to use an .ICS file because each time clients will download the whole file, plus it will get huge !!! Did you progress on your side ?

Comment: Unfortunately no progress on the filtering issue. [CALDav](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CalDAV) seems more made for events sharing.

Comment: Next try I will do is to set up a CalDAV server (SabreDAV or DAVical) and try to keep their database up-to-date with my application database (maybe with triggers or smth else...). This way I think it could work. What do you think ?

Comment: This seems to be a hard work. Not sure you have the choice but duplicating data seems not to be a good idea for me. And it will generate superfluous traffic. There should be a way to directly interface your database. In another hand maybe a CalDAV server could be able to read in your database directly.

Comment: Do you have good source for documentation and examples how to use iCal in our solutions. Actually, we are looking to create iCal object (file) that will be used in syncing with other websites (e.g. AirBnB)? All suggestion on this topic are more than welcome!