# iCal - Remote query filter

Tags: http, icalendar

Maybe dumb question but I'm wondering how iCal clients query a remote calendar.

I've just created a little web service that generates an iCal file. This file is successfully interpreted by Google Calendar and Lightning (new Sunbird). But I'm not filtering on any range of time.

I imagine that Google and Sunbird clients gives parameters to filter on dates at least.

How can I know what are these parameters ? Is it part of the iCal RFC ?

Can someone point me to the good direction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are just 'subscribing', you're simply downloading the entire file and that's it. No filtering.

However, when you're talking about syncing, the place you need to look at is CalDAV.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791

This is a WebDAV based protocol most major calendar applications use, and does do things like filtering on time ranges and 2-way synchronization.

Comment: Ok I see. However iCal is still the most supported format isn't it ?

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY iCalendar is the format, iCal is the Apple application. Subtle difference, but the answer is yes :)